# Blackberry Web Browser (4.6.1) and display block elements

Tags: html, css, blackberry

I am having real issues with the Blackberry web browser (specifically under version 4.6.1) in that I need to set an image as a clickable link, but the browser does not always recognised the full image as clickable if I just wrap an anchor tag around the image.

But if I set the anchor to display:block; in CSS, the Blackberry browser forces width:100%; on it regardless of whether I set my own width in CSS - all block display elements seem to be forced to 100% width regardless of my own wishes.

Has anyone come across it before?  Can anyone suggest a solution?

The page is very very trivial, and I am using HTML 4.01 Transitional for the doctype.

Regards

Moo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
.class {
    display:block;
    width:50px !important;
}
```